# How do I keep my textbox from adding a number that I do not want?

Tags: .net, vb.net

My code works well except for when I add an over or under number that I do not want. How do I modify my code so that the unwanted number doesn't show up in the listbox. Also on my arrays I thought that (10,100) would only accept numbers 10 through 100.

```
Private Sub GoBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoBtn.Click

    If GotxtBox.Text < 10 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can not be less than 10")
    End If
    If GotxtBox.Text > 100 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Can not be grater than 100 ")
    End If

    Dim number As Integer = Val(GotxtBox.Text) ' get number
    ' add the number to the end of the numberListBox
    GoLstBox.Items.Add(number)

    If ArrayCountInteger(10, 100) = 10 Then 'only allows  10 numbers but not necessarly 10-100???
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered the maximum number of items")
        Return
    End If
    numberArray(ArrayCountInteger(10, 100)) = GotxtBox.Text
    ArrayCountInteger(10, 100) += 1
    GotxtBox.Clear()
    GotxtBox.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: how are `numberArray` and `ArrayCountInteger` declared?

Comment: You *really* need to set **Option Strict On** - it will point out several problems in your code for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably need a return(Exit Sub maybe in vb am c# background)

```
If GotxtBox.Text < 10 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Can not be less than 10")
    Exit Sub or Return'Am not sure about this(but return in c#)
End If
If GotxtBox.Text > 100 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Can not be grater than 100 ")
    Exit Sub or Return
End If
```

Comment: Be sure - `Exit Sub` is correct :) (Also "grater" should be "greater", that is not your error.)

Comment: @AndrewMorton That a VB.net developer will be knowing when I just point out it right? I hope `Return` should work In VB we use `Exit Sub` so confused

Comment: Yes, `Exit Sub` is correct. `Return` will also work, but `Return` is more usually used with a function.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you want your code something more like the following, which checks if the input can be converted to an Integer:

```
Dim arrayCount(99) As Integer
' (...other code...)

Private Sub GoBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GoBtn.Click

Dim nInput As Integer

' can we parse the input as an Integer?
If Not (Integer.TryParse(GotxtBox.Text, nInput)) Then
    MsgBox("I could not parse that as a whole number. Please try again.")
    Exit Sub
End If

If nInput < 10 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Can not be less than 10")
    Exit Sub
End If

If nInput > 100 Then
    MessageBox.Show("Can not be greater than 100")
    Exit Sub
End If

' add the number to the end of the numberListBox
GoLstBox.Items.Add(nInput.ToString())

If arrayCount(nInput) = 10 Then 'only allows 10 numbers
    MessageBox.Show("You have entered the maximum number of items.")
    Exit Sub
End If

arrayCount(nInput) += 1
GotxtBox.Clear()
GotxtBox.Focus()
End Sub
```